# Difference between "Descendant User Objects" and just "User Objects"

Tags: active-directory, permissions, delegation, organizational-unit

i am trying to delegate permissions on a cetain OU to a certain group. All i find is "Descendatn User Objects" and not just "User Objects" ; we have those available in other domain; please do let me know what is the difference and how does it effect?

Comment: DUO's are in 2008, UO's are in 2003.  I don't think there is a difference in functionality.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please answer in a seperate comment so that i can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DUO's are in 2008, UO's are in 2003. I don't think there is a difference in functionality, probably just a clarification in 2008 in regards to the wording.

Comment: What if you upgrade from a 2003 domain? Is it changed to "User Objects" or is it still "Descendant User Objects". Just curious.